# Orchard CMS - Creating a new Widget

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

I'm trying to write an Orchard Widget, but the page ([Writing a Widget](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-widget)) appears to be out of date.

Specifically, this piece of code does not compile as AlterTypeDefinition does not exist on 1.4:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("MapWidget", cfg => cfg
.WithPart("MapPart")
.WithPart("WidgetPart")
.WithPart("CommonPart")
.WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));
```

Any pointers on what has replaced it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that hits this - its because AlterTypeDefinition is an extension method.

Add the following using:

```
using Orchard.ContentManagement.MetaData;
```